# How to make a scrolling in AdapterViewFlipper faster?

Tags: android, xml, animation, widget

I want to improve rate of a speed autoscrolling of a text in a widget

```
 <AdapterViewFlipper
         android:id="@+id/ticker_adapter"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:scrollHorizontally="true"
         android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
         android:background="#00000000"
         android:loopViews="true"
         android:configure="com.migdesign.bictiproreader.ConfigActivity"
         android:flipInterval="25000"
         android:autoStart="true"
         android:layoutAnimation="@anim/anim_controller"
         >
```

i try to use android:layoutAnimation="@anim/anim_controller"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
         android:toXDelta="0%"
         android:duration="2000"/>
```

anim controller

```
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:animation="@anim/animticker" />
```

Comment: guess what "flip interval" means in english ... but if "autoscrolling" means the speed of animation ... then guess what "duration" means

Comment: when i use "flip interval"=25 000 it shows me a text 25 seconds, but i want to improve speed of an animation

Comment: than change the duration of animation ...now it takes 2 sec.

Comment: wiget works with my animation as it works without it... I'm not sure that i use it correct